# Office-addin review testing notes 1220.4.1

Tags: excel, office-store, custom-functions-excel

Got below review comments from Microsoft team

> **Validation**
>
> **1220.4.1  Testing Notes**
>
> Your add-in contains custom functions, but no testing notes were
> included with your offer submission. Please re-submit your offer with
> testing notes for the custom functions.

But where do I have to add this testing notes? Thanks!

Comment: Customer Service questions are off topic here. Please open a Customer Support ticket instead
https://aka.ms/marketplacepublishersupport 
1.    Browse topics Category: Commercial Marketplace
2.    Topic: Certification issue
3.    Next step: Review solution

Comment: @OfficeStoreDeveloperComms Thanks for the information but as a note, there's a "Contact us" link on those submission reports that redirect to stackoverflow. See here: https://ibb.co/C8g1jZw

Answer (score 1):

you could add a testing note file in your project when submit your add-in. The validation team need the information to test if the function can work cross platform.