# How to fix the issue with 220.2.1 Custom Functions Metadata Files during Office 365 add-in publication

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins, office365-apps, office-store

Our attempt to publish the add-in was rejected with the following description

> 1220.2.1 Custom Functions Metadata Files It appears that custom functions HTML and Javascript metadata files are missing in your
> manifest.
>
> Please notice that your offer must host all custom functions HTML,
> Javascript, and JSON metadata files on the same domain. Please update
> the location of the custom functions metadata files and re-submit your
> offer.

But we configured our Excel Add-in to use a shared JavaScript runtime according to documentation and the sample on OfficeDev gitlab repository.

[Shared runtime link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/configure-your-add-in-to-use-a-shared-runtime)

[GitLab link](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-OfficeAddins/blob/master/Samples/excel-shared-runtime-scenario/manifest.xml)

All custom function are inside index.html. In the manifest, the resource is represented as <bt:Url id="SharedAddin.Url" DefaultValue="https://ourDomain.com/excel-plugin-js-version/" />.

In our manifest there is link to custom function metadata file (<bt:Url id="Functions.Metadata.Url" DefaultValue="https://ourDomain.com/excel-plugin-js-version/functions.json"/>).

All custom functions files are hosted on the same domain. The index.html file URL: https://ourDomain.com/excel-plugin-js-version/ and the functions metadata file URL: https://ourDomain.com/excel-plugin-js-version/functions.json.

Could somebody help us with the issue identification, please?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add corresponding contents based on the response. Please refer to the comment in [Office-addin review testing notes 1220.4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63268525/office-addin-review-testing-notes-1220-4-1) :

> Please open a Customer Support ticket instead http://aka.ms/marketplacepublishersupport 1. Browse topics Category: Commercial Marketplace 2. Topic: Certification issue 3. Next step: Review solution